# How to rename an object created within a function each run?

Tags: r, function, object, rename

I made a function that generates a data frame. Since I want to store my data frame, I saved it in the global environment. I want to run the function again, but with new parameters and avoid overwriting my previous data frames. Basically, I want to rename my data frame each time I run my function.

```
fun <- function(x, y) { 
  a <- x*1000
  b <- a + pi
  c <- a + b
  return(data_frame <- data.frame(a, b, c))
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The way that you have your code right now will not execute.

Comment: Actually, I think that like this, instead of a data frame, the output is a list =S

Comment: Not sure if this is true of your actual code, but you're missing a closing parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution

```
fun <- function(x, y, name) { 
a <- x*1000
b <- a + pi
c <- a + b
assign(deparse(substitute(name)),data.frame(a, b, c), envir=.GlobalEnv)}

fun(1,2,df.name)
df.name
```

This returns:

```
     a      b      c
1 1000 1003.1 2003.1
```

Comment: Thanks, this is useful. But is there a way to specify it in the function?

Comment: Yes, although the new name will be a required input in your function. See my edit